# iOS NSZombiesEnabled = YES

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, nszombieenabled

I found this bit of code online to check if my NSZombiesEnabled is on or off

```
if( getenv("NSZombieEnabled") || getenv("NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled") ) {
    NSLog(@"NSZombieEnabled/NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled enabled!");
}
```

The strange thing is that if in my env. variables in XCode4 I set NSZombiesEnabled = NO then the code still shows it to be set. Only if I completely remove the setting does it not show.

I believe NSZombiesEnabled creates one gaping memory leak so I want to be sure that just setting the env. variable to NO also disables it.

Cheers
Nick

Comment: The purpose of zombies is to leak memory oO

Answer (score 3):

Setting the variable to `"NO"`, doesn't disable it — it just sets the variable to `"NO"` and the framework checks the value itself. You have to check if it's equal to the string `"NO"`. The if-statement doesn't check if a value says `"no"`, it checks if the value is `empty`, `nil`, `NULL`, zero, etc.